# How can i change shape of legend jquery flot

Tags: jquery, css, charts, flot, legend

I'm finding about `jquery flot`. And when i draw two lines, it displayed two legends with rectangle shape.

But i want to change these default shape of `jquery flot`.

One shape is **rectangle** (wind direction), another shape is **line** (wind speed).

Here is expected image:
[image]

But i don't know how can i do that ? Hope everybody can support me.

Thank you very much.

Here my demo: [link demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/517/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i found solutions for this case.

I only modified `css` of this legend.

```
$("#flot-placeholder .legendColorBox div div").eq(1).css("border", "1px solid #980000").css("width", "35px");
```

This is link demo: [link demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/518/)